# Error de warning MSB3187 en VS2022 Aplicación de Escritorio Windows Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estimada Comunidad.

Tengo una aplicación Windows Forms que trabaja En Capas

.Net FrameWork 4.8, EF6, Visual Studio 2015, Crystal report para la version de VS2015

Esta fue migrada a: Visual Studio 2022 y Crystal report para VS 2022.

Cuando hago la compilación de la aplicación funciona perfectamente, sin embargo quiero entender porque me da este error de warning.

Esta es la salida de la compilación

```
Operación Recompilar iniciada...
1>------ Operación Recompilar todo iniciada: proyecto: GridExtension, configuración: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Operación Recompilar todo iniciada: proyecto: Entidades, configuración: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  GridExtension -> C:\Proyectos\Erp\GridExtension\bin\Debug\GridExtension.dll
2>  Entidades -> C:\Proyectos\Erp\Entidades\bin\Debug\Entidades.dll
3>------ Operación Recompilar todo iniciada: proyecto: Sms, configuración: Debug Any CPU ------
4>------ Operación Recompilar todo iniciada: proyecto: Reportes, configuración: Debug Any CPU ------
5>------ Operación Recompilar todo iniciada: proyecto: Datos, configuración: Debug Any CPU ------
4>  Reportes -> C:\Proyectos\Erp\Reportes\bin\Debug\Reportes.dll
3>  Sms -> C:\Proyectos\ErpSms\Sms\bin\Debug\Sms.dll
5>  Datos -> C:\Proyectos\Erp\Datos\bin\Debug\Datos.dll
6>------ Operación Recompilar todo iniciada: proyecto: Negocio, configuración: Debug Any CPU ------
6>  Negocio -> C:\Proyectos\Erp\Negocio\bin\Debug\Negocio.dll
7>------ Operación Recompilar todo iniciada: proyecto: Erp, configuración: Debug Any CPU ------

7>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): warning MSB3187: El ensamblado al que se hace referencia 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.dll' se aplica a un procesador diferente del de la aplicación.
7>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): warning MSB3187: El ensamblado al que se hace referencia 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer.dll' se aplica a un procesador diferente del de la aplicación.
7>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): warning MSB3187: El ensamblado al que se hace referencia 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls.dll' se aplica a un procesador diferente del de la aplicación.
7>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): warning MSB3187: El ensamblado al que se hace referencia 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel.dll' se aplica a un procesador diferente del de la aplicación.
7>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): warning MSB3187: El ensamblado al que se hace referencia 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.dll' se aplica a un procesador diferente del de la aplicación.
7>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): warning MSB3187: El ensamblado al que se hace referencia 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel.dll' se aplica a un procesador diferente del de la aplicación.
7>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): warning MSB3187: El ensamblado al que se hace referencia 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.dll' se aplica a un procesador diferente del de la aplicación.
7>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): warning MSB3187: El ensamblado al que se hace referencia 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion.dll' se aplica a un procesador diferente del de la aplicación.
7>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): warning MSB3187: El ensamblado al que se hace referencia 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory.dll' se aplica a un procesador diferente del de la aplicación.
7>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): warning MSB3187: El ensamblado al que se hace referencia 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Prompting.dll' se aplica a un procesador diferente del de la aplicación.
7>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): warning MSB3187: El ensamblado al que se hace referencia 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.dll' se aplica a un procesador diferente del de la aplicación.
7>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4164,5): warning MSB3187: El ensamblado al que se hace referencia 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize.dll' se aplica a un procesador diferente del de la aplicación.
7>  Erp -> C:\Proyectos\Erp\Erp\bin\Debug\Erp.exe
========== Recompilar todo: 7 correcto, 0 con errores, 0 omitido ===========
========= Recompilar se inició en 9:08 AM y tomó 10.119 segundos ==========
```

Le agradezco a ustedes por su valiosa ayuda que me puedan dar.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Un warning no es un error. Una señal de advertencia no es lo mismo que una señal de prohibido estacionar.

Lo que dice MSDN de ese warning es que, si tienes en el proyecto un target platform (*processor architecture*) definido como neutral (MSIL) y los ensamblados que referencias no son neutrales (están definidos para x86 o para x64), entonces Visual studio va a advertir ésto.

Para que no salga, simplemente hay que ver que la aplicación no es para "Any CPU" y hacer que coincida la arquitectura con los dll usados (todo x64, todo x86... etc).

En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425571/236345) sugieren ajustar el csproj así

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <!-- some code goes here -->
    <ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
        None
    </ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
    <!-- some code goes here -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Ok, Entiendo. Muchas Gracias